# Search doesn't return results unless type is defined

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to ElasticSearch and I decided to use it as a search engine on my project. I was working on a local ElasticSearch 1.5.0 version and everything was working fine: all the queries and filters returned the right results. 
Then I switched to use the ElasticSearch of the company, which was running version 1.4.2 and because of that the filters didn't work. We upgraded ElasticSearch to version 1.6.0 and it worked once again. 
After removing and indexing all the information again, the queries aren't working anymore.

If I specify the type of document I want to look for, this query works just fine:

```
GET /epg/program_elk/_search/
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {   
            "must": [
            {
                "bool": 
                {   
                    "should": [
                    {
                        "match": 
                        {
                            "title": "Simpsons"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "original_title": "Simpsons"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "match": 
                {
                    "category": 42
                }
            }
        ]}
    }
}
```

However, if I use:

```
GET /epg/_search
```

Which should search for all the types in the index, it doesn't work. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part isn't working? Do you get an error? I wasn't able to reproduce this with similar data

Comment: I don't get any kind of error. The "generic" search just doesn't return any kind of data. When the same query is applied to a certain type, i.e., "program_elk", it works just fine! It's as if the overall search is not accepting any kind of filters...

Comment: Do you have fields in different types with the same name but different mappings?

Comment: No I don't. Also I tested the search right now and didn't do any changes to ElasticSearch or the search script and it worked. I don't know what's happening.